# Google Play Store Feedback

Tags: android, google-play

Within a review, I read that an app does not work on device X and Y. (By the way - not my app)
But that's interesting.
What is the best way to resolve an issue if an app does not work on 2 devices? Usually, users are providing a simple, small sentence (app does not work on X) and nothing more.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**What is the best way to resolve an issue if an app does not work on 2 devices?**

To resolve this type of issue we have a certain checklist for our app.

1. We have active technical support. With this, we ask the users to report issue to our support and then we can track down and resolve the issue.
2. For those who do not report the issue, we can check device details for particular review on Developer Console under Ratings & Reviews section and try to reproduce issue at our end.
3. If our app having any Architecture-specific compiled libraries ex. FFMPEG, OPENCV then we have to check Native Platform of this particular device.

For example:
[image]

4. We can check user specific database if our app is utilizing the server-side database.
5. Crashes & ANRs in Developer console is also helpful to get details and solve users issue.
6. [NOT RECOMENDED] We can block particular device from Developer console in APK-> Supported Devices(see list) -> uncheck the checkbox which is adjacent to the device, so the PlayStore doesn't list our app in this device anymore to install.

Answer (score 0):

You should consider using something like Fabric : https://fabric.io/ by twitter.
It has most of things we need to keep track of our apps with a fancy UI and its most important its free.

It has following notable features:

1. Easy integration with the app
2. Shows total online users at current time (live)
3. Shows detailed crash reports with entire exception trace and device information including memory and battery information.

Get started here: https://fabric.io/kits/android/crashlytics/install